# Redshift - Cannot load query results into table - leader node issue

Tags: amazon-redshift

My goal is it to load query results to a table to store an ordered list of column names for a given table.  (Then I will stuff all these column names, into a single column, using the listagg function which I will pass to dynamic sql.)  The reason I cannot load this into a table is because system table queries compute on leader nodes, yet this query does not execute on a leader node, and there is no way to force it to execute on a leader node.  Any ideas how to get this to execute successfully?

```
create table temp_columns
as
select
cast(t1.columnname as varchar) as columname
--,
--cast(t2.ordinal_position as integer) as ordinal_position
FROM 
(

SELECT 

        cast(schemaname as varchar) as schemaname,
        cast(tablename as  varchar) as tablename,
        cast("column" as varchar) as columnname

FROM PG_TABLE_DEF
WHERE 
schemaname = 'schema1'
and tablename = 'table1'
)
t1
 join information_schema.columns t2
    on t1.schemaname = t2.table_schema 
    and t1.tablename = t2.table_name
    and t1.columnname = t2.column_name
WHERE 
t1.schemaname = 'schema1'
and t1.tablename = 'table1'
order by t2.ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

We got around this by creating the table first, then doing a INSERT INTO.

so something like:

```
create table public.temp_columns
(
columname varchar(255),
ordinal_position int
);

insert into public.temp_columns
select
cast(t1.columnname as varchar) as columname,
cast(t2.ordinal_position as integer) as ordinal_position
FROM 
(

SELECT 

        cast(schemaname as varchar) as schemaname,
        cast(tablename as  varchar) as tablename,
        cast("column" as varchar) as columnname

FROM PG_TABLE_DEF
WHERE 
schemaname = 'schema1'
and tablename = 'table1'
)
t1
 join information_schema.columns t2
    on t1.schemaname = t2.table_schema 
    and t1.tablename = t2.table_name
    and t1.columnname = t2.column_name
WHERE 
t1.schemaname = 'schema1'
and t1.tablename = 'table1'
order by t2.ordinal_position;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I tried your suggestion on redshift, and still get the error "SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables."  Any other suggestions?